# How is message framing handled in Transit, if at all?

Tags: clojure, transit

I'm looking at using the Transit format (https://github.com/cognitect/transit-clj) for a simple TCP message streaming application. One thing I'm having trouble figuring out from the documentation is whether or not the Transit libraries will handle message framing for me. Does the wire format define some kind of message delimiter or encode the size of each message in some way? Or would it be my responsibility to extend the binary format to make it suitable for streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transit piggiebacks on JSON, so over the wire it has the same properties as a JSON document. There's no delimiter as such and no message length inside the message.